# How to create a kernel thread in atomic context and use it multiple times [BUG: Scheduling while atomic]

Tags: multithreading, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, atomic

I need to kthread_run in a driver kernel code. This thread tends to turns an LED on/OFF where the device is transmitting data. So basically I won't want the transmission be slowed down be cause of the LED blinking delay time. 
I would like to create a thread somewhere around packet transmission code so the thread will do the LED blinking process based on the rate of transmission. 
But apparently creating a thread  there requires interaction with the thread scheduler, which is not allowed at interrupt/atomic context and will generate the BUG:Scheduling while atomic. according to my research,an approach could be to create the kernel thread elsewhere, and queue interrupt request processing to it. Can someone please elaborate this a bit more?
So this is not a case where we have interruption thread. I basically need a Function that has it's own thread away from my main thread. And I will call this function anytime! Please let me know if this is still unclear. Thanks.

Comment: Can't you use the existing LED API built into the kernel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't actually want a kernel thread.  You want a workqueue.  You can queue a worker function from your interrupt top-half, and the kernel will run it in process context as soon as it has time.  If you can avoid sleeping, you can use the shared queue via the functions `schedule_work()` and `schedule_delayed_work()`.

To avoid sleeping, queue one work function to turn on the LED.  At the end of that function, queue a delayed work function to turn it off.

If you instead want to do a simple `TURN_ON(); sleep(); TURN_OFF()`, you'll need to create your own workqueue at module init, and submit to that using `queue_work()` and `queue_delayed_work()`

Reference:
http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-7-sect-6

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So does that mean using kthread is a wrong approach for this situation?

Comment: Well, the workqueue is actually queuing the work to a kernel thread, which is exactly what you're asking for.  A kthread is not for repeatedly spawning, it's for setting up once.  The workqueue abstraction is a way to bundle up a small task and ask the kernel to execute it in a different context.  Just about every interrupt handler in Linux has a top-half (fast, interrupt context) and a bottom-half.  Often, the bottom-half is a workqueue function.